# tricopter simulation to test control algorithms

Tags: control, quadcopter, simulator

I am looking to write and test my own control algorithms for tricopter flight. I am looking for a simulator that can simulate a tricopter but at the level of receiving simulated PWM and returning simulated gyro, compass and other sensor readings. Ideally it would also have graphics for visualization (need not be fancy). Ultimately, I want to port this to a real tricopter but at the moment I would just like to simulate it. Any suggestions for free simulators that are low level as I described?

Comment: Matlab/Octave with your own physical model of the aircraft?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a framework that compiles both as an AVR program to run directly on Multiwii board and also having the option to test the algorithms as a desktop 3D app. The 3d app is based on the irrlicht game engine.

It can be found here: https://github.com/mkschreder/bettercopter